# CMake error when configuring itkvtkglue

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, vtk, itk

My question is similar to [Emre's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894600/how-to-use-itkvtkglue-to-use-itk-with-vtk). I am trying to build the  [itkImageToVTKImageFilter example from the wiki](http://www.itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/Smoothing/DiscreteGaussianImageFilter#Download_and_Build_DiscreteGaussianImageFilter). I hope to use it for a Gaussian low pass filter that I plan to apply to an image. After I download the itkvtkglue, extract it to a folder, and then press configure in Cmake, I receive the following error message:

```
Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 9 2008
Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 9 2008 -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 9 2008
Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 9 2008 -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
CMake Error at F:/ITK/ItkVtkGlue/bin/UseItkVtkGlue.cmake:10 (include):
include could not find load file:

G:/VTK/UseVTK.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:13 (include)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I was not sure what could be causing the error but I suspected that it had something to do with my Windows system path. However, it also seems to be pointing to the correct folder (PATH goes to F: drive). The error indicates that Cmake is looking within G: drive for some unknown reason.

Here is the CMakeLists.txt for itkImageToVTKImageFilter:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(DiscreteGaussianImageFilter)

find_package(ITK REQUIRED)
include(${ITK_USE_FILE})
if (ITKVtkGlue_LOADED)
  find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
  include(${VTK_USE_FILE})
else()
  find_package(ItkVtkGlue REQUIRED)
  include(${ItkVtkGlue_USE_FILE})
  set(Glue ItkVtkGlue)
endif()

add_executable(DiscreteGaussianImageFilter MACOSX_BUNDLE DiscreteGaussianImageFilter.cxx)
target_link_libraries(DiscreteGaussianImageFilter
  ${Glue}  ${VTK_LIBRARIES} ${ITK_LIBRARIES})
```

I read that this was a very common problem but I am unsure how to correct it. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I am still very new to Stackoverflow so let me know if I need to provide more info.

Comment: Did you move VTK from G:/VTK after you built the binaries at that location?

Comment: @drescherjm I am honestly not sure, but I might have had multiple external hard drives connected at that time, which is why the letters shifted around. The source is on C:/. Would there be a way to redirect after building?

Comment: Set VTK_DIR in cmake-gui to the folder that you built vtk. This is not the source folder but the build folder.

Comment: I would also rename or delete the g:\vtk folder so cmake does not find it again..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works now. I needed to rebuild ITK with ITK_BUILD_ALL_MODULES on as well as checking the Module_ITKVtkGlue which I didn't do before.